# Sliding Drawer layout Problem in android

Tags: android, layout, slidingdrawer

hi i have put Sliding drawer in my application

but this takes Space like in below Image if drawer is open

[image]

and if it is close then it looks like

[image]

[image]

My layout is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:gravity="bottom" android:background="@drawable/androidpeople">
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Content">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button02"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:text="Content">
         </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Content">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Content">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button02"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:text="Content">
         </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Content">
        </Button>

    </LinearLayout>
    <SlidingDrawer 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer" 
        android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton" 
        android:content="@+id/contentLayout" 
        android:padding="10dip" 
        android:layout_height="250dip">
        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton" 
            android:background="@drawable/closearrow">
        </Button>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/contentLayout" 
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:gravity="center|top" 
            android:padding="10dip" 
            android:background="#C0C0C0" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button android:id="@+id/Button01" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Content">
        </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button02"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
             android:text="Content">
         </Button>
        <Button android:id="@+id/Button03" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Content">
        </Button>
</LinearLayout>
    </SlidingDrawer>
</LinearLayout>
```

My problem is even drawer is closed it takes space and i want to remove it so that first button top of the screen can come down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try changing your outermost layout to a `relativelayout`. this should allow the sliding layout to overlap the linearlayout above it when it expands.

Comment: Hey it works fine i have not thought to use relative layout thanks

Comment: Using frame layout as the root layout is normally recommended.