# Sliding Drawer Not Showing

Tags: android, scrollview, slidingdrawer

I want to have a sliding drawer which shows up at the bottom of my view but it currently does not show.  I have also tried using a linear layout as the root with the scroll view have a weight of 1 but that caused the scroll view and its contents to not show. Any ideas?

My View:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:context=".AddScheduleItemActivity" >

        .
        .
        .

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollLayout"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hadsfndle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sdf" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```

Thanks,
Nathan

[image: How it should look]

In the picture I want the blue to be the scroll view and contents and the green to be the handle for the slider.

Tried following some other suggestions and came to this which still doesn't work. The contents of the scrollview show fine but the slider is not shown. Need some more suggestions! Thanks!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        .
        .
        .

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollLayout"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hadsfndle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sdf" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Well it appears that sliding drawer is no longer supported so I guess I will look for an alternative :(

Comment: Can you please let me know where exactly you want your slider? At the bottom of screen or at the top of screen ? I have tested your layout and its showing slider at the bottom and opens from bottom to top.

Comment: I want it at the bottom. With the layout I posted you may see the slider because there is nothing in the linear layout. Add a bunch of elements until they exceed the space on the screen. At that point the scroll view pushes the slider handle off the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to show your sliderdrawar at bottom, try below code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <SlidingDrawer
            android:id="@+id/SlidingDrawer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="250dip"
            android:content="@+id/contentLayout"
            android:handle="@+id/slideHandleButton"
            android:padding="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/slideHandleButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
            </Button>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#C0C0C0"
                android:gravity="center|top"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="10dip" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button01"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Content" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button02"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Content" >
                </Button>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Button03"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Content" >
                </Button>
            </LinearLayout>
        </SlidingDrawer>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If above code is not solve your issue then change parent layout to `LinearLayout` give `weightsum=10` and then distribute among your `scrollview & sliderDrawer` to equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Add `layout_alignParentBottom` on your `SlidingDrawer`.

```
 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your question had already been answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044094/sliding-drawer-layout-problem-in-android).

Try this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        .
        .
        .

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>

<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/slidingDrawer1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:content="@+id/content"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/handle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Handle" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hadsfndle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sdf" />
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>

</RelativeLayout>
```